# optimizing a sql query with a large number of records being joined and combined

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

This is my code currently and what is does is: it groups records with the same IDs(KEYVADD) and then it removes them based off of the having statement.

As it stands right now this query take 5-10 minutes to run because the audit file is very large and then joins and select statements.  I am hoping to reduce this time but I'm struggling to do it in a way that will still return the same results.  When I have tried to but what is in the HAVING into the WHERE statement it just pulls the orders with nulls in the status slots instead of the times instead of getting rid of the ID all together.

```
DECLARE @paramdate DATETIME , @paramdatechar varchar(30),@warehouse int
set @warehouse = 711
set @paramdate= '2018-05-17 12:00:00.000'
set @paramdatechar = CONVERT(varchar(30),@paramdate,121)



exec('  select KEYVADD
    ,min(case when VALUADD=0 then timestmp else null end) as "Status0"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=2 then timestmp else null end) as "Status2"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=4 then timestmp else null end) as "Status4"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=5 then timestmp else null end) as "Status5"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=7 then timestmp else null end) as "Status7"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=8 then timestmp else null end) as "Status8"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=9 then timestmp else null end) as "Status9"
    ,min(nmdoh) as "Customer"
    ,min(c.scscn) as "Container"
    ,min(whsoh) as "Warehouse"
    ,min(preoh) as "Preorder"
    from Audit a
left outer join orderhp h on left(a.KEYVADD,7) = h.ONHOH
left outer join ordercnhpc on h.onhoh = c.onhcn
WHERE 
    whsoh = '''+@warehouse+'''
    and IMGTADD = ''A''
GROUP BY KEYVADD
HAVING(
     (min(case when VALUADD=2 then timestmp else null end) <= '''+ @paramdatechar +''')
        and (
                (
                min(preoh) = ''Y''
                and(  
                    (min(case when VALUADD=4 then timestmp else null end) IS NOT NULL)
                    or   (min(case when VALUADD=5 then timestmp else null end) IS NOT NULL)
                    or   (min(case when VALUADD=7 then timestmp else null end) IS NOT NULL)
                    or   (min(case when VALUADD=8 then timestmp else null end) IS NOT NULL)
                    or   (min(case when VALUADD=9 then timestmp else null end) IS NOT NULL)
                    )
                )
                or
                (
                min(preoh) = ''N''
                )
            )
        and(
                (
                    min(case when VALUADD=7 then timestmp else null end) IS NULL
                    and  min(case when VALUADD=8 then timestmp else null end) IS NULL
                    and  min(case when VALUADD=9 then timestmp else null end) IS NULL
                )
                or
                (
                    min(case when VALUADD=7 then timestmp else null end) >= '''+ @paramdatechar +'''
                    or   min(case when VALUADD=8 then timestmp else null end) >= '''+ @paramdatechar +'''
                    or   min(case when VALUADD=9 then timestmp else null end) >= '''+ @paramdatechar +'''
                )
            )
        ) ') at IBMAS400
```

**Results:**

```
    793841800 2018-05-16 14:46:24.5720000   2018-05-16 13:20:25.2250000 2018-05-16 14:46:36.8530000 NULL    NULL    2018-05-17 13:57:03.0230000 NULL    name 1                  711 N
    793843700 2018-05-16 14:46:24.6410000   2018-05-16 13:20:27.2830000 2018-05-16 14:46:36.8750000 NULL    NULL    2018-05-17 13:57:03.5800000 NULL    name 2                      711 N
    793847800 2018-05-16 14:46:24.7080000   2018-05-16 14:21:21.8600000 2018-05-16 14:46:36.9820000 NULL    NULL    2018-05-17 13:57:04.0010000 NULL    name 3                  711 N
    793849100 2018-05-16 14:46:24.7400000   2018-05-16 14:21:23.5210000 2018-05-16 14:46:37.0430000 NULL    NULL    2018-05-17 13:57:04.3380000 NULL    name 4                      711 N
    793855500 2018-05-16 15:49:01.7590000   2018-05-16 15:21:18.1300000 2018-05-16 15:49:15.5260000 NULL    NULL    2018-05-17 13:57:05.0660000 NULL    name 5                  711 N
    793856100 2018-05-16 15:49:01.7810000   2018-05-16 15:21:19.2200000 2018-05-16 15:49:15.5520000 NULL    NULL    2018-05-17 13:57:05.5630000 NULL    name 6                  711 N
    793865100 2018-05-16 19:54:46.2840000   2018-05-16 16:19:53.7890000 2018-05-16 19:54:57.1080000 NULL    NULL    2018-05-17 13:57:05.9330000 NULL    name 7                      711 N
    793871500 2018-05-16 19:54:46.3350000   2018-05-16 17:20:24.8500000 2018-05-16 19:54:57.1820000 NULL    NULL    2018-05-17 14:07:04.8690000 NULL    name 8                  711 N
```

I am hoping there is a way I can reduce the time on this either by changing how the select works or some other way and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How many records are we talking? A million? Ten Million?

Comment: the total number at the moment is 31 million

Comment: Is the line "left outer join ordercnhpc on h.onhoh = c.onhcn" supposed to  be "left outer join ordercnhp c on h.onhoh = c.onhcn"?  Can you tell me what table (VALUADD, nmdoh, whsoh, preoh) are in?  Do the tables have indexes, and if so what are they on?

Comment: yes that is what it is supposed to be.  it must have gotten messed up when copying it over.  and VALUADD is in the AUDIT file, nmdoh, whsoh and preoh are in the orderhp .  I edited my last comment cause i figure it out and its aroudn 31million records.  my bad but what do you mean by indexes?

Comment: I'd say you'd be hard pressed to reduce that query time without putting the data in a separate table or data warehouse cube that caches. I agree that indexing may work as well, but with that many records, you have to maybe think about it like "do i need to run through them all to get the answer, or can i calculate once, and then continue to insert and calculate on a smaller set of data". Also, the word Outer usually indicates you want a record even when a match on the join doesnt exist, that may be the source of the null? Just some thoughts.

Comment: Yeah you may be right, maybe my problem lies with the outer joins.  It might be better for me to look at a different kind of join as well. I will look into those.  I will look further into indexing as well and see if i can get that going.

Comment: Queries are a bit easier to advise on when the fields' tables are obvious; editing the question so the field names are all qualified with their owning tables could help you get better advice.

Comment: A few more tips -- adding an execution plan would let people help more.  picking a database - also helpful as you're currently tagged mysql, sql, sqlserver and ibm-midrange (which makes me think db2).

Comment: thank you for the tips! I will work on the post and make sure to be more clear in future posts.

Comment: Besides some of the other suggestions (indexing), I also wonder if you couldn't be better served by including other fields in Group By rather than using min().  It's hard to say without the schema.  You might also want inner joins if you are just going to throw out NULL values anyway.  More clarity in the question will allow us to provide more specific answers.

Comment: What database are you actually using? SQL Server, or DB2 on i, or mysql?

Comment: This query would error out with a message like 'table not found: ordercnhpc'

Comment: Also, this bit - left(a.KEYVADD,7) - cannot use an index, so could  be tremendously slow

Comment: HAVING(
     (min(case when VALUADD=2 then timestmp else null end) <= '''+ @paramdatechar +''')
        and (  that looks really expensive why can't you filter these out in the join or a where statement.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/

Can you try this and see if it is faster?  Also why do you even need to join to the ordercnhp table if you commented out the field c.scscn in the select?

--,min(c.scscn) as "Container"

```
DECLARE @paramdate DATETIME , @paramdatechar varchar(30),@warehouse int
set @warehouse = 711
set @paramdate= '2018-05-17 12:00:00.000'
set @paramdatechar = CONVERT(varchar(30),@paramdate,121)



exec('  select KEYVADD
    ,min(case when VALUADD=0 then timestmp else null end) as "Status0"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=2 then timestmp else null end) as "Status2"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=4 then timestmp else null end) as "Status4"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=5 then timestmp else null end) as "Status5"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=7 then timestmp else null end) as "Status7"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=8 then timestmp else null end) as "Status8"
    ,min(case when VALUADD=9 then timestmp else null end) as "Status9"
    ,min(nmdoh) as "Customer"
    --,min(c.scscn) as "Container"
    ,min(whsoh) as "Warehouse"
    ,min(preoh) as "Preorder"
    from Audit a
left outer join orderhp h on left(a.KEYVADD,7) = h.ONHOH
-- Is the ordercnhp needed?
--left outer join ordercnhp c on h.onhoh = c.onhcn
WHERE 
    whsoh = '''+@warehouse+'''
    and IMGTADD = ''A''
GROUP BY KEYVADD
HAVING(
     (min(case when VALUADD=2 then timestmp else null end) <= '''+ @paramdatechar +''')
        and (
                (
                    min(preoh) = ''N''
                )
                or
                (
                    min(preoh) = ''Y''
                    and(  
                            (min(case when VALUADD in (4,5,7,8,9) then timestmp else null end) IS NOT NULL)
                        )
                )
            )
        and(
                (
                    min(case when VALUADD in (7,8,9) then timestmp else null end) IS NULL
                )
                or
                (
                    min(case when VALUADD in (7,8,9) then timestmp else null end) >= '''+ @paramdatechar +'''
                )
            )
        ) ') at IBMAS400
```

Comment: that did seem to make it faster!  thank you for that!

Comment: i actually removed that a while ago to test if it was quicker to not join that file at all and forgot to uncomment it. so it is supposed to be in there i just forgot to remove the --.

Comment: Ok check into indexes and SQL Query Analyzer if your using Microsoft SQL. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650689.aspx